# Converting urlilb code to Kivy UrlRequest

Tags: python, http, request, kivy

Do you guys have an idea how covert the following code using UrlRequest?

I need to convert the code from the run method to use UrlRequest, but I've been facing some difficulties since I'm not skilled with https requests.

Do you have any idea on how to convert the code that uses urlilb to UrlRequest?

I see that Kivy doesn't work great with the code below when I generate the apk.

Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

import json
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen

gui = '''

WindowManager:
    MainMenu:

<MainMenu>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: sample
            text: 'Sample'

        Button:
            text: 'Run'
            on_release: root.run()

        Button:
            text: 'Exit'
            on_release: app.stop()

'''

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(gui)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainMenu(Screen):
    
    def run(self):
        headers = {
            'X-Cosmos-Token': 'XXX',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'User-Agent': 'Cosmos-API-Request'
        }

        base_url = 'https://api.cosmos.bluesoft.com.br/gtins/7896051020158.json'
        request = urllib.request.Request(base_url, None, headers)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        data_content = json.loads(response.read())
        sample = data_content['description']
        self.ids.sample.text = sample

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: what is the problem? I don't see `UrlRequest` in your code. You could atleast try to use it in code. And documentation for [UrlRequest](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html) shows that it can be similar to `urllib`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I need to convert the method `run()` to use `UrlRequest` instead of `urllib`.

I'm still learning and don't have any idea on how I should do it because of the headers.

The method below searches for a product in a website called BlueSoft Cosmos. It uses a barcode specific for Brazilian products `https://api.cosmos.bluesoft.com.br/gtins/7896051020158.json` called GTIN, and it returns a json after using some headers.

The BlueSoft Cosmos offers an API which allows this kind of search through code.

It works great on a desktop, but on Buildozer apk it doesn't. That's why I've been looking for a way to use it with UrlRequest from kivy.

```
def run(self):
        headers = {
            'X-Cosmos-Token': 'XXX',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'User-Agent': 'Cosmos-API-Request'
        }

        base_url = 'https://api.cosmos.bluesoft.com.br/gtins/7896051020158.json'
        request = urllib.request.Request(base_url, None, headers)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        data_content = json.loads(response.read())
        sample = data_content['description']
        self.ids.sample.text = sample
```